# Multivariate Logistic Regression in Tensorflow without Built in Optimizers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to construct a multi-class logistic regressor on 25112 28x28 images that are handwritten, from 0-4, by implementing stochastic gradient descent with L2 regularization, but without use of traditional tensorflow functions (I'm trying to build it from scratch). I'm new to this so it's possible I've made a few mistakes. Thank you for taking the time!

I believe I'm:

Reading in the training and testing images correctly

Have set up the tf.Session() correctly

I'm trying to print out the results for the learned weights and the corresponding bias, but I'm not sure I'm doing that correctly.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Program2edited.py", line 87, in <module>
    test_lr()
  File "Program2edited.py", line 83, in test_lr
    print(classifier.predict((y1)))
  File "Program2edited.py", line 72, in predict
    return softmax(tf.matmul(x, self.W) + self.b)
  File "C:\Users\Person\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\o
    a = ops.convert_to_tensor(a, name="a")
  File "C:\Users\Person\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\f
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\Person\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\f
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Person\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\f
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "C:\Users\Person\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\f
    _GetDenseDimensions(values)))
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       ...,
       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)] - got shape [1, 4983, 1, 784], but wanted [1].
```

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("C:/train_data/*.jpg")
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(images, 28, 28)
image.set_shape((28, 28, 1))
images = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 784])
# `image_batch` contains 25112 consecutive images, packed into a single tensor.
image_batch = tf.train.batch((images,), 25112)

test_filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("C:/test_data/*.jpg")
test_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(test_filenames)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, test_image_file = image_reader.read(test_filename_queue)
test_images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(test_image_file)
test_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(test_images, 28, 28)
test_image.set_shape((28, 28, 1))
test_images = tf.reshape(test_image, [-1, 784])
# `test image_batch` contains 4983 consecutive images, packed into a single tensor.
test_image_batch = tf.train.batch((test_images,), 4983) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    image_tensor2 = sess.run([image_batch]) 
    test_image_tensor2 = sess.run([test_image_batch])
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1./(1+ tf.exp(-x))

    def shape(tensor):
        s = tensor.get_shape()
        return tuple([s[i].value for i in range(0, len(s))])

    def softmax(x):
        e = tf.exp(x - tf.reduce_max(x))
        return e 

    class LogisticRegression(object):
        def __init__(self, input, label):
            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [25112, 784]) #784=28*28
            self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [25112, 5])
            self.W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 5])) 
            self.b  = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))  

    def train(self, lr=0.1, input=None, L2_reg=0.01):
        if input is not None:
            self.x = input 
        p_y_given_x = softmax(tf.matmul(self.x, self.W) + self.b)
        d_y = self.y - p_y_given_x
        x_transpose = self.x
        self.W += lr * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(self.x), d_y) - lr * L2_reg * self.W
        self.b += lr * tf.reduce_mean(d_y, axis=0)

    def negative_log_likelihood(self):
        sigmoid_activation = softmax(tf.matmul(self.x, self.W) + self.b)
        cross_entropy = - tf.reduce_mean(tf.add((self.y * tf.log(sigmoid_activation)), (1 - self.y) * tf.log(1 - sigmoid_activation)), axis=1)
        return cross_entropy


    def predict(self, x):
        return softmax(tf.matmul(x, self.W) + self.b)

def test_lr(image_tensor2 = image_tensor2, test_image_tensor2 = test_image_tensor2, learning_rate=0.01, n_epochs=200):
    x1 = image_tensor2
    y1 = test_image_tensor2

    classifier = LogisticRegression(input=x1, label=y1)
    for epoch in range(0, n_epochs):
        learning_rate *= 0.95
        classifier.train(lr=learning_rate)
        cost = classifier.negative_log_likelihood()

    print(classifier.predict((y1)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_lr()
```

Comment: the code is very unorganized. Create the model first and then create the session to run the model. ` self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [25112, 784]) #784=28*28, self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [25112, 5])` this does not look right.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of weird things in this code. For example, classifier.train doesn't actually train the classifier, it just builds ops to do so. You need to create a session to run ops in tensorflow.

I recommend starting from the [basic tutorials in the tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mandelbrot).